# javabridge.jutil.JVMNotFoundError: Can't find the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, python, weka

I want to use Weka in my python code, so I install java-wrapper python(2.7.16 ) according to https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/install.html and my java version is:
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Also, I added the JDK path to  user variable PATH according to https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-java-virtual-machine-jvm-not-found-error/

but it raise error:

```
   >>>import os
   >>>import traceback
   >>>import weka.core.jvm as jvm
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\weka\core\jvm.py", line 17, in 
   <module>
    import javabridge
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\__init__.py", line 38, in 
    <module>
    from .jutil import start_vm, kill_vm, vm, activate_awt, deactivate_awt
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 151, in 
    <module>
    os.pathsep + os.path.join(find_javahome(), "bin")
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 139, in 
    _find_jvm
    raise JVMNotFoundError()
    javabridge.jutil.JVMNotFoundError: Can't find the Java Virtual Machine
```

Comment: Did you install a 64bit version of Python 2.7? See [this post](https://intelligea.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/check-if-python-version-is-64-or-32-bit/) on how to determine the bitness of your Python shell.

Comment: my Python shell is 64 bit (2.7.16.amd64.msi) I find a guide in https://forum.image.sc/t/error-when-trying-to-open-cellprofiler-analyst/12572/6 but I don`t understand the final solution. I am using Windows 10, Does it may be related to my Windows?

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: yes, for both user variable and system variable --> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin and JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin –

Comment: while setting JAVA_HOME omit bin directory. set it like: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181. bin directory is used while setting path

Comment: I removed "bin" but the problem not solve:  >>>import javabridge -->     ...      
    raise JVMNotFoundError()
JVMNotFoundError: Can't find the Java Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Windows user and setting up Python always seems to be riddled with issues... But I finally had some time setting up a Windows 10 instance... Here is what I did:

- no `JAVA_HOME` variable defined
- Location of java executable:

```
where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

- Java version installed:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

- VC++ compiler for Python 2.7 (for compiling javabridge)

  http://aka.ms/vcpython27
- Anaconda for Python 2.7 (4.3.0.1)

  https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86_64.exe
- value of PATH after installing anaconda:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Anaconda2;C:\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\fracpete\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

- create anaconda environment for pww (numpy needs to be installed through anaconda):

```
conda create -n py27-pww numpy
```

- activate environment:

```
activate py27-pww
```

- installing pww:

```
pip install python-weka-wrapper
```

- testing pww:

```py
python
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
jvm.start()
from weka.classifiers import Classifeir
cls = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.trees.J48")
print(cls)
jvm.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I did steps above and I used py27-pww (it seems that the problem related to PATH is solved).

Comment: >>> jvm.start()
    DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Adding bundled jars
    DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Classpath=['C....']
     DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:MaxHeapSize=default
     DEBUG:weka.core.jvm:Package support disabled

Comment: >>> from weka.classifiers import Classifeir
     ..../usr/share/java/weka.jar:/usr/share/java/libsvm.jar 
     not found. Ensure the file is installed or update your environment's WEKA_JAR_PATH to only include valid locations.

Comment: Read the documentation on [how to start the JVM with package support](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/api.html#java-virtual-machine) (off by default) and [how to handle packages](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/api.html#packages) within pww.